# Replace 2 or more spaces in a file with NULL

Tags: bash, unix, sed

Using sed, how can I replace 2 or more white spaces with NULL?

Input

```
200 0 0  100      300    400 10
```

Desired output

```
200 0 0100300400 10
```

Comment: `replace with NULL` - do you mean `remove`?

Comment: Yes, i meant remove. Got the solution Ed.
Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `sed` (this is not specific to GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/[ ]{2,}//g' filename
```

or (without `-r`):

```
sed 's/[ ]\{2,\}//g' filename
```

For your input, this would produce:

```
200 0 0100300400 10
```

Comment: No need to put the space in a character list as there's nothing special about it. You should probably state it's GNU-specific too so the poster doesn't waste time trying to debug it if (s)he's on, say, Solaris.

Comment: A more basic regex would be `s/   *//g` -- two spaces followed by zero or more spaces, or with generic whitespace: `s/[[:space:]][[:space:]][[:space:]]*//g`

Comment: @EdMorton (1) This isn't GNU-sed specific, and would work well with other sed variants.  (2) I understand that a space isn't special, but I find it readable to have quantifiers when matching more than one space.

Comment: It won't work with sed on Solaris, for example, so maybe non-portable is more appropriate than GNU-specific? I always thought using EREs in sed was GNU-specifc (whether with -r or escaping ERE constructs) though - if not, what is it? The comment about the space was that you don't need `[ ]`, just a simple space char on it's own is fine.

Comment: @EdMorton The variant without `-r` doesn't use ERE, does it?  It seems that my understanding of [regular expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html) is rather limited.

Comment: @EdMorton BTW, both the variants suggested above _seemed to work well_ using BSD sed.

Comment: Yeah, I just checked and I'm surprised to see that at some point RE intervals as specified by `\{2,\}` became part of POSIX BREs, they're just not handled as such by all seds. I guess if it's defined by POSIX maybe you don't need to say anything?

Answer (score 5):

This will work with any sed, not just GNU sed:

```
sed -e 's/   *//g'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
sed 's/  \+//g' INPUTFILE
```

will work (if you have GNU sed).

Comment: You should state it's GNU-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Posting here for reference, an `awk` solution:

```
$ echo '200 0 0  100      300    400 10' | awk '{gsub(/  +/,"")}1'
200 0 0100300400 10
```

Comment: Since awk uses EREs the gsub() can be `gsub(/  +/,"")`.

Comment: Oops, you're right and you saved a character. Thanks @EdMorton. Updated the answer. `:)`

Comment: It may not be an issue but the script as posted will also remove blank lines. `'{gsub(/  +/,"")}1'` would be safer. Of course, now we've lost those saved characters again :-).

Comment: I was thinking of using `NF` but that would add 1 character. `;)`

Comment: Using `NF` again would delete blank lines. Without the `1` it would have removed lines with no double-spaces as well, though.

Comment: @EdMorton Aah scratch that. Ill get more coffee! `:)`.

Answer (score 0):

Pure Bash. In a script you could use a parameter substitution:

```
str="200 0 0  100      300    400 10"

shopt -s extglob

str=${str// +( )/}
echo  "$str"

200 0 0100300400 10
```

The substitution `${str// +( )/}` deletes all whitespaces followed by at least one whitespace.